# Jssor Slider: Is there a way to have img thumbnail nav and caption with FX?

Tags: slideshow, thumbnails, slide, captions

I have both a Jssor slider with pic thumbnails and a Jssor slider with active captions working but cannot seem to combine them in one slider that has both and works. Is it possible to have both in one slider? What would I add to one or the other to do that? I am not a programmer, just barely familiar with the code enough to adjust it. Thanks for your time and effort!

Comment: You'll need to provide a specific code snippet(s) in order for us to analyze and assist you in your question.  Please don't paste everything either, narrow down your problem area and you'll get much better feedback.

Comment: You need a slider that enable both caption and thumbnail, right?

Comment: Yes, that's right. How much of a snippet from each one do you need?